# Import dta into R: get rid of Stata formatting

Tags: r, import, format, stata

I used `read_dta` to import Stata files into R. I am trying to get rid of `attr(,"format.stata")` which seems to have been stored into a list.

I tried different things based on my google search but none of them have worked.

```
> df2$peer_id_spec[[1]]
[1] 41
attr(,"format.stata")
[1] "%9.0g"
> df2$peer_id_spec <- zap_labels(zap_formats(df2$peer_id_spec))
> df2$peer_id_spec[[1]]
[1] 41
attr(,"format.stata")
[1] "%9.0g"
> df2$peer_id_spec[[1]]
[1] 41
attr(,"format.stata")
[1] "%9.0g"
> df2$peer_id_spec <- zap_formats(df2$peer_id_spec)
> df2$peer_id_spec[[1]]
[1] 41
attr(,"format.stata")
[1] "%9.0g"
> df2$peer_id_spec <- zap_formats(zap_labels(df2$peer_id_spec))
> df2$peer_id_spec[[1]]
[1] 41
attr(,"format.stata")
[1] "%9.0g"
> df2$peer_id_spec <- zap_labels(zap_formats(df2$peer_id_spec))
> df2$peer_id_spec[[1]]
[1] 41
attr(,"format.stata")
[1] "%9.0g"
```

Comment: Have you tried [zap_formats(df2)](https://haven.tidyverse.org/reference/zap_formats.html) ?

Comment: Also worth noting that these are _attributes_ that describe your data frame - not the data itself - so unless they are causing you some issue, you can leave them alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete them.

```
dta <- haven::read_dta(path)

attributes(dta$sepallength)  ## has format.stata attribute
# $label
# [1] "Sepal.Length"
# 
# $format.stata
# [1] "%9.0g"

dta <- lapply(dta, `attr<-`, 'format.stata', NULL)  ## delete attributes
attributes(dta$sepallength)  ## cleaned
# $label
# [1] "Sepal.Length"
```

Alternatively use `readstata13::read.dta13`.

```
dta <- readstata13::read.dta13(path)
attributes(dta$sepallength)  ## no attributes
# NULL
```

---

*Data:*

```
path <- system.file("examples", "iris.dta", package = "haven")
```

Comment: thank you! how can I do this for every column in the dataframe/data.table?

Comment: @PaulaSpinola I'm not quite sure about your data since it's not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it looks nested somehow. But try `df2$peer_id_spec[[1]] <- lapply(df2$peer_id_spec[[1]], `attr<-`, 'format.stata', NULL)`.